# Peewee - Set a default time as a future datetime

Tags: python, peewee

I'm trying to have a column on one of my tables have a default value of whenever the entry is created + 2 weeks.

Here is the column definition I currently have:

```
   dt_end = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow + datetime.timedelta(weeks=2))
```

This returns an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Any clue on how to work around this ?

EDIT:
I haven't put the parenthesis on the `utcnow` because otherwise all default time will be on server spin up. This allows Peewee to use the function as a default each time instead of the value. That is where the problem lies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
def two_weeks():
    return datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=14)

dt_end = DateTimeField(default=two_weeks)
```

Comment: Of course that makes sense, why didn't I think of it... Thanks a lot ! Love what you do BTW !

Answer (score -1):

[utcnow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) is a method you're missing the call operator (parenthesis)

```
import datetime

default=datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(weeks=2)
```

Comment: Nope, that won't work. I missed explaining that in the question but I haven't put the parenthesis because otherwise all default time will be on server spin up. This allows  Peewee to use the function as a default each time instead of the value. That is where the problem lies